# Hybris Create Web Service with Intellij

Tags: rest, web-services, intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm really new in Hybris. I have Hybris commerce 6.4 and im working with Intellij.

Can anybody tell me how to create a web service rest?

I need the basic steps or a hello word example of a web service exposed from hybris.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hybris is based on Spring, you can create rest web services just as you would do on a normal Spring MVC application. 
You can also generate a web service extension using ant extgen, this way you will generate a Ycommercewebservices extension with some rest controllers that you can use as an example.

Comment: Which template do you recommend to use?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mension. Ycommercewebservices

Comment: I have done the extension with the ycommerwebsevices template and the same time Im working with my project that is an extension of the yempty template and I create a basic controller class for my webservice. Do you know if I need a extra configuration in some xml? because I execute my service at the navigator and only get a 404 Error

Comment: Did you add your extensions to localextensions.xml inside config folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can check webservice extension. Create new extension from it.